# Creating a morphology tagging/labeling model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

I had an idea of building a model using machine learning or deep learning in order to perform morphological tagging/labeling on untagged/unlabeled data.

I have a lot of tagged/labeled data (about 30,000-40,000 entries), so I thought of creating this model to help the ones that are responsible for it to avoid this task in the future.

The problem is I don't know where to start and when I searched the web about it I found almost nothing helpful, I want to do it in a **Semitic language**.

How can I accomplish such a task?

> I've searched the web a lot about it but I mostly get stuff that is not Semitic language and not morphological way.

Comment: Im not 100% sure this question belong on this website, if you think it's more suitable to a different one please tell me so I can move it there

Comment: I did a Google Scholar search for `morphology tagging` and found 334,000 articles. The sixth result is specifically about morphology tagging in Arabic. Presumably, there are many more such articles. I think this answers the bulk of your question. If you have a more specific question, please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As Sycorax pointed out correctly, a simple search would have sufficed to get closer to a solution: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=morphology+tagging

This article in particular fits your problem well:

> Roth, Ryan, et al. "Arabic morphological tagging, diacritization, and
> lemmatization using lexeme models and feature ranking." (2008).

https://academiccommons.columbia.edu/doi/10.7916/D8SN0J8X/download [download link]

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with research papers, I tried reading it but I'm not so sure as to how to go and implement it based on the article, can you help or do you know a guide for understanding it?

Comment: I you cannot grasp the gists of the paper, you will probably not be able to train a deep learning language model by yourself. This is a task that requires years of experience and is mostly done with a team of engineers, not as a single person. I'd suggest looking into more "beginner-friendly" projects and resources, before taking the task of training your own LLM. https://developers.google.com/machine-learning is a great resource by google to get started with understanding Machine Learning :)